# Change logging level for sbt project using Play's Logger

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I have a sbt project that uses Play 2.2 as a dependency. When a program is run in the console, only ERROR level messages show up. How do you change the level so INFO, DEBUG levels are printed?

example ERROR level output:

```
18:36:22.388 [run-main-1] ERROR application - Message
18:36:22.389 [run-main-1] ERROR application - Message
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Check if play application logging level is set properly:

> You can override log levels in application.conf as follows:
>
> # Root logger:
>
> logger.root=DEBUG

for more detailed information see this article: [Play 2.2 logging configuration](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger)

also be sure that your sbt has proper logging level:

`$ sbt --debug`

for more detailed information see this article: [sbt 13.2 logging configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Howto/logging.html)